# Font rendering issue, breaking fonnt

Tags: jquery, css

I have text rendering issue with Poppins font I used

```
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;   
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;   
font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

this code but still facing the same issue:

[image]

Comment: So what's your problem? Also there is no such property as `font-smoothing` in CSS, it should be `font-smooth`.

Comment: You Can Try to Setting in Chrome for font rendering : https://coderwall.com/p/9tecwq/fix-poor-font-rendering-in-chrome-on-windows

Comment: ok i will check thank you

Answer (score 0):

"font-smoothing", as well as "font-smooth", are not valid CSS rules. Try to play around with the properties: "antialiased" and "grayscale". It might help.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to a question, should be a comment. Please see [When should I comment?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).
  Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post; instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).